# Remove post type filter added by the plugin in the final query

Tags: wp-query, filters

I am querying the post types based on the custom post type, but when printing the final query it also includes the `post_type='tribe_events'`, which is due to plugin using for the events. But I have added the following parameters only in the query:

```
  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mycustomepost',
        'posts_per_page'=>1     
    );
```

How to remove the events post type filter from the query?

Comment: Hello, what template is this in? Could you also provide more code. Your sample has no context.

Comment: i am using the custom template for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best course of action would be to prevent the plugin from doing something you don't want. If for some reason this is not possible you can use the filter [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to change the query before it is executed, like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse239465_force_post_type', 9999);

function wpse239465_force_post_type () {
  $query->set('post_type', 'mycustomepost');
  }
```

Note that this will force the post type on all your queries, given that the priority of 9999 guarantees it is the last filter applied and there is no condition attached to `$query->set`. So you may at least want to add some [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

Comment: yes, that is working for me, but did i need to add this filter every page where i am using wp_query ?

Comment: No, you add this in `functions.php` and it will apply to all your templates. But then it will also affect all your queries. That's why you may want to add a conditional.

Comment: but that will effect the plugin working , if using in the functions.php

Comment: Yes. So you add a conditional to make sure it works only on specific templates.

Comment: like `is_post_type_archive()` and/or `is_singular( 'mycustomposttype' )`